# PHP AJAX Object text variable error

Tags: php, ajax

I have a  variable, `answer_body`

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#postAnswer').click(function () {


          var answer_body = document.createText(oDoc.innerHTML);

          $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            cache:false,
            url:"ajaxfile/ajax_submit_answer.php",
            data:"answer_body="+answer_body,  
            success: function (msg) {
              alert('Answer submissiondone');

            },
            error: function() {
                alert('Answer submission Failure');
            }
          });

        });
    });
```

At the other end in PHP file when I tried to enter this value into the database, `[Object text]` is being shown.

The PHP file have been double checked, no problem there. This might be happening because I am storing a whole innerHTML inside a variable. (the html might be: `<b>&nbsp;hello</b><i>&nbsp;world</i>`)

I want to store the entire bold text to be stored in database. How can I do that?

Comment: My suggestion would be to alert(oDoc.innerHTML) and then alert(document.createText(oDoc.innerHTML) to see what you're getting, then go from there.  Your snippet doesn't work.  Maybe just include it as code instead of a snippet?

Comment: For debugging, I would suggest using `console.log( _stuff here_ );` and using the browsers developer tools and console tab to actually see whats going on better. As alert(); doesn't support displaying a whole lot of data you would find in console.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just get the content of your `<div>` :

```
var answer_body = oDoc.innerHTML ;
```

In addition, you may encode your POST content using [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) :

```
var answer_body = encodeURIComponent(oDoc.innerHTML) ;
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please, check this anwser as accepted to close your question. Thanks.

Comment: Did this answer help you?